# i get an Error on beginreceivewhen using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am creating a socket connection to a unit here to open a door.  I manage to create a connection and can even send a command, but i get a weird error on the BeginReceive function.  It says "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced" with errorcode 10045.

Here is my code:

```
private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
```

```
tcp = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            TimeoutObject.Reset();
            tcp.BeginConnect(endPoint, tcpConnected, tcp);
            TimeoutObject.WaitOne(5);
            if (!tcp.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection timed out");
                tcp.Close();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            tcp.Send(OPENDOOR);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            tcp.Send(CLOSEDOOR);

            Console.WriteLine("Send Successful");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            tcp.Close();
```

```
private void tcpConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!tcp.Connected)
                    return;
                //doQueue(eventType.CONNECTED);
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                TimeoutObject.Set();
                client.EndConnect(ar);
                client.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.Truncated, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                //doQueue(eventType.DEBUG, "Connect was cancelled" + e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                //doQueue(eventType.DEBUG, "Unhandled error" + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

the tcp.send methods actually do what they are supposed to, i hear the doorlock open and close.  But the beginreceive error has me puzzled for a while now.  I also have a receivedata function but i will not post this because i never get into this function, it throws an exception before.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the address family and make sure you have an IPV4 (not IPV6).  Many people are using old code with following line : IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];    The zero index on many machines are IPV6 so you need to change to index 1 which is IPV4.

Comment: i found the solution but unsure why this is the solution.  Apparently the socketflags.truncated was causing it to error.  I changed it to None and it works flawlessly now

Comment: Don't know why you were using the truncate option. Very unusual.There is a flag in the TCP Header which allows truncation. TCP datagrams are around max 1500 bytes.  The truncation allow the max 1500 to be ignored. I never used the option.The 1500 can vary by a few bytes because the TCP specification allow different vendor options.  So when you client and server are from different vendors the size change by a few bytes. but each vendor is suppose to be able to work with any other vendor.  The flag I think was to ignore errors when size was different.  But compatibility should not create errors.